# Yii2 extend or replace core class

Tags: yii2

I'd like to either extend or replace `yii\db\ActiveQuery` with my own class and have the entire application use it.

This is to bring in the `@alias` functionality referenced by CedricYii at the bottom of [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7263).

Due to the private nature of some of the changed functions, I'll probably have to replace it.

Is this possible? Or will I have to fork the repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Dependency Injection Container](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html) for this.

Write down in your application bootstrap code:

```
Yii::$container->set('yii\db\ActiveQuery', 'app\components\ActiveQuery');
```

Comment: Any idea why it didn't work for core Validator?

Yii::$container->set('yii\validators\Validator', 'app\components\Validator');

Comment: Does this 'extend' or just replace the class? Is this the same as setting `Yii::$classMap['yii\db\ActiveQuery'] = '@common/components/ActiveQuery.php';`?

Comment: Also, I can get this to work with ActiveQuery but not `\yii\db\Query` - any ideas?

Comment: @SilverFire where do i put this? it's not set in main.php?