# Override Yii2 Class

Tags: php, yii2

Assuming yii2-app-advanced. I would like to override the base implementation of `\yii\helpers\Inflector::hasIntl()` which is used (indirectly) by `yii\web\Response`.

**original code**

```
protected static function hasIntl()
{
    return extension_loaded('intl');
}
```

**the code I want**

```
<?php

namespace backend\components;

class Inflector extends \yii\helpers\Inflector
{
    protected static function hasIntl()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, I create `backend\components\Inflector` extending `yii\helpers\Inflector` and override the method as shown above.

Then in `backend/config/bootstrap.php` I add:

```
Yii::$container->set('\yii\helpers\Inflector', '\backend\components\Inflector');
```

But is not using the custom implementation. It keeps using the original one. So, questions:

- why is not working?
- a good alternative solution? (a posted an ugly one)

I have read [Yii2 extend or replace core class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756307/yii2-extend-or-replace-core-class) and used this `Yii::$container->set` method before, but in this case is not working, even if done like:

```
Yii::$container->set('\yii\helpers\Inflector', [
    'class' => '\backend\components\Inflector',
]);
```

Comment: I know nothing about Yii, but here's a [related issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-core/issues/176) if that can help. Looks like you can just define a class `yii\helpers\Inflector` yourself and have it extend `yii\helpers\BaseInflector` (which contains the default implementation). Not sure that's what you're looking for (and not sure it even works, but some people mention it).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reference. Interesting thread. But he finally don't say where to put the file to do the override. And I don't think is correct to create a class with the same namespace than the original. I'm tying to do the extend version, and tell the framework to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-overview#customizing-helper-classes) confirms this approach, but the class-mapping looks a little different:

```
Yii::$classMap['yii\helpers\Inflector'] = '@app/components/Inflector.php';
```

Comment: Yes, this was the "ugly" solution I implemented. But in this case the new file is actually replacing the original one. With same namespace and everything.

Comment: Well, at some point one has to tell the framework which class to use... and with framework classes this works a little different (one may call it ugly), than with common application classes. Leaving a comment suggested, because it changes the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't consider this an elegant solution**

I was able to solve it by using:

```
Yii::$classMap['yii\helpers\Inflector'] = '@path/to/new/file'
```

But this doesn't looks as elegant as the other solution, as is replacing the file. In this case the new file have to have the original namespace `yii\helpers\Inflector` and extend `yii\helpers\BaseInflector`.